# What could cause Run-time error 1012 Error accessing application data directories

Tags: windows, vb6, runtime-error

Friend of mine has a problem :).

There is an application written in Visual Basic 6.0 (not by him).

One of users reported that when it run on Windows 2000 and tried to scan folders on disk it raised box with message:

*Run-time error 1012 Error accessing application data directories*

We couldn't google anything about it and didn't find anything about runtime error 1012 in VB6 help files.

My guess was that VB calls some old API function which returns folder to which app has no access (private, ciphered, belongs to other user and app is run by user without needed privileges).

But we could not reproduce this (on Windows XP professional).

Anyone meets with bug like this in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 1012 is rather generically ERROR_CANT_READ. See this [Microsoft list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681383(VS.85).aspx), but it also implies it refers to the registry.

You could try running SysInternals [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to look for failing file/registry operations by the process.